# How to add canvas tag in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch

Any Body Know how to add canvas tag in sencha

```
 html: <canvas width='500' id='canvas' height='100'/>,
```

but i dont know where to define canvas and how to call it in sencha

Comment: Any Tutorial will Be Great for Me  THanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can just define an Ext.Component in your Viewport, or whatever panel you are working with and set the html property to be `<canvas../>` Then whenever you need to reference it you can either get it by id (unrecommended) or by getting the reference to the component and accessing its el.dom

A developer had a blog post on it here:
http://j-query.blogspot.com/2011/02/sencha-touch-ipad-signature-javascript.html

Comment: i have seen this code earlier ,but not getting the code ,basically my requirement is to draw a smiley in sencha touch